# Use sample() function within mutate() and case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr, sample, mutate

Let's say my input dataset is given by df2:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,NA,6,NA), b = c(2,4,5,1))
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| NA | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| NA | 1 |

I would like to create a third variable called "c" which takes the value of b if a is not missing. If a is missing (row 2 and row 4), c takes randomly the value or 0 or b.

In termes of programmation, I was thinking about doing something like that:

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(c=case_when(is.na(a) ~ sample(c(0,b),n(),replace=TRUE),
                                  TRUE ~ b))
```

But it doesn't give me the result I want.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sample` function won't vectorize the way you want in this case. We could use `if_else` instead

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(c=case_when(is.na(a) ~ if_else(runif(n()) <.5, 0,b),
                     TRUE ~ b))
```

We use `runif()` to draw a random number for each row. If it's less than .5 we return 0, otherwise we return b. For example

```
set.seed(369)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(c=case_when(is.na(a) ~ if_else(runif(n()) <.5, 0, b),
                     TRUE ~ b))
#    a b c
# 1  1 2 2
# 2 NA 4 0
# 3  6 5 5
# 4 NA 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some mathematical operations:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(c = b * (runif(n()) > 0.5))^is.na(a))
   a b c
1  1 2 2
2 NA 4 4
3  6 5 5
4 NA 1 0


df2 %>%
  mutate(c = b * (runif(n()) > 0.5))^is.na(a))

   a b c
1  1 2 2
2 NA 4 4
3  6 5 5
4 NA 1 1

df2 %>%
  mutate(c = b * (runif(n()) > 0.5))^is.na(a))

   a b c
1  1 2 2
2 NA 4 0
3  6 5 5
4 NA 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `apply` solution, in case you want to use `sample`:

```
set.seed(1111)

df2$c <- apply(df2, 1, \(x) ifelse(is.na(x["a"]), sample(c(0, x["b"])), x["b"]))

df2
   a b c
1  1 2 2
2 NA 4 4
3  6 5 5
4 NA 1 1
```

##### EDIT:

I would advice against the use of `apply`, unless you have to use it. It is more than a 100x slower as the `mutate` approach by @Mr.Flick:

```
    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
1  apply          100  127.97  118.491    127.75     0.11         
2 mutate          100    1.08    1.000      0.86     0.22
```